# Create a text file with date and time as the filename

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a text file with Visual Studio in VB.Net, and I want the filename to be the current date and time.

I have this code:

```
Dim d As System.DateTime
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
Dim filepath As String = d + ".txt"
If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
    System.IO.File.Create(filepath).Dispose()
End If
```

But every time I use `d` it gives me the `System.NotSupportedException` error. I can only create a text file by specifying the filename. How can i fix it and make my text file's name the current date and time?

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails to assign a value to the variable called `d`. Also, you want `d` to be a string, not a DateTime. Finally, the `/` and `:` characters in from your date and time are not valid in a windows filename. Either remove them or replace them with valid characters. Replace your first three lines of code with:

```
Dim d As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss")
Dim filepath As String = d & ".txt"
```

Comment: Thanks @VisualVincent I just did that.

Comment: @Mental In addition to what Blackwood wrote, you should also use a full path for the file so that it knows and you know which directory it will be in.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I want the file to be in the same directory of the .exe, so my code works perfectly, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying with '/' and ':' in file name, while creating file this special characters not allowed.

```
Dim dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss")
Dim filepath As String = dateString + ".txt"
If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
System.IO.File.Create(filepath).Dispose()
End If
```